# Reading a line's number in a file

Tags: python, file

Currently I have:

```
for line in f:
    if line == promble:
        print("check")
```

I want to make the program print the line after the line I have selected. Help.

Comment: What you trying exactly ?

Comment: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a line in a file, and if it matches print the next line in the file, try:

```
selected = False
for line in f:
    if selected:
        print line
        selected = False
    if line == promble:
        selected = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate`

```
for index,line in enumerate(f):
    if line == promble: 
        print f[index+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `file` object `f` has an `__iter__` attribute, so you can apply `next` to get the next item in your loop:

```
for line in f:
    if line == promble:
        print(next(f)) # prints next line after the current one
```

If `f` is neither a `file` object nor an `iterator`, you can call `iter` on `f` to make one:

```
it = iter(f)
for line in it:
    if line == promble:
        print(next(it))
```

If `f` was already an iterator, calling `iter` on `f` will return `f` again, so it still works fine.